# After force stop, next notification not triggered in android phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am using local notification plugin in my application. Here i set notification like alarm. Its working fine. what ever time i set in my database, alarms are working fine.
But while i force stop the application(Setting->Applications->Manage applications->MyApplication->ForceStop), next alarm is not coming. any one can help me?.. i tried with following link,
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/android-broadcast-receiver-change-in.html
but still is not working.

Answer (score 0):

force stop app will remove alarm associated with the app

so your pending task will never be done.

read in details:
http://blog.csdn.net/gemmem/article/details/8858461